# Jqgrid multiselect dropdown with scrollbar

Tags: jqgrid

I want to add multiselect dropdown with chechbox in my application , i had added it , it works perfecty . Multiple selection is enabled but it's height is not getting set , here is my view ... please help

View

```
jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({

                subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {

                },

                autowidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: true,
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAllTasks","AdminIndex")',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                height: 'auto',
                colNames:['Task Id ','Project Name', 'Assign To','Task Name','Task Description','Budget','Task Status','Start Date','End Date'],
                colModel:[


                    {name:'Task_Id', key: true,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','ne','gt','ge','lt','le']}, index:'id', width:20, sorttype:"int", editable: true, editable: true, sortable: true, search: true, searchrules: { required: true}},
                    {name:'Project_Name',index:'pid', width:40,search:false,editrules: { required: true},editable: true,formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 1},editoptions:{size:"1",value: projects}, style: "width: 180px",edittype: "select", stype: "select",dataheight:'auto'},                                               
                    {name:'User_Email',stype: 'select',index:'email',searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','ne']},searchoptions:{ value: users }, width:60,editrules: { required: true},edittype: 'select',editable: true,editoptions:{size:5,value: users,dataInit: function (elem) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(elem).multiselect({
                            header:"Choose an option!",
                            minWidth: 100, //'auto',
                            height: 600,
                            selectedList: 7,
                            checkAllText: "all",
                            uncheckAllText: "no",
                            noneSelectedText: "Any",
                            open: function () {
                                var $menu = $(".ui-multiselect-menu:visible");

                                $menu.width("auto");
                                return;
                            }
                        });
                    }, 50);
                    },multiple: true,defaultValue: 'IN'},editrules: { required: true},edittype: "select", stype: "select"},
                    {name:'Task_Name',index:'tname', width:40,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','ne']},editrules: { required: true},editable: true,editoptions:{size:"20",maxlength:"30"},editrules: { required: true}},
                    {name:'Task_Description',index:'Task_Description',width:90, edittype: "textarea",editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"21"},search: false,editable: true,editrules: { required: true}, classes: "textInDiv"},
                    {name:'Task_hrs',index:'taskhrs', width:20,search:false,editrules: { required: true,number:true},editable: true,editoptions:{size:"20",maxlength:"30"},editrules: { required: true}},
                    {name:'Task_Status',index:'tstatus',searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','ne']},searchoptions:{ value: getAllSelectOptions() }, width:25, editable: true,search:true,editrules: { required: true},  editoptions:{value: getAllSelectOptions()},edittype: "select", stype: "select"},
                    {name:'Task_Start_Time',sortable:false,search:false,width:30, editable:true,editrules: { required: true},formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d/M/Y "} },
                    {name:'Task_End_Time',sortable:false,width:30,search:false, editable:true,editrules: { required: true},formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d/M/Y "} },
                  //  {name:'CreatedTimeStamp',sortable:false,width:30, editable:false,search:true,editrules: { required: true},formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d/m/Y H:m:s"} },
                   // {name:'ModifyTimeStamp',sortable:false,width:30, editable:false,search:true,editrules: { required: true},formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d/m/Y  H:m:s"}},


            ], 
});
```

Comment: You still don't answer on the questions which I multiple asked you in previous comment: which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). One sees that you use some `multiselect` plugin. Which one and in which version? The line `$('.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css({ 'overflow-y': 'scroll' });` is absolutely unclear too. You use multiselect plugin in `editoptions`. Which editing mode you use? It's good to include screenshot(s).

Comment: v5.0.2 of jqgrid

Comment: I develop **alternative** fork [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) and can't help you with commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). You can post your questions on [Guriddo forum](http://guriddo.net/?forum=guriddo-js) or to wait that other developers probably help you. In any way you should edit the text of your question and add the name of the jqGrid product, the version number **and the name of multiselect plugin and the version number** to your question. You should write **which editing mode** you use (form editing, inline editing or cell editing).